# Select2 - Fetch data from backend and add options to selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm currently trying to get select2 to work, however, I'm struggling a little bit right now. What I want to achive, is fairly simple: I fetch a JSON from a webserver which consists out of key/value pairs (one ID to one string). After fetching those, I want to create options out of those and add them to select2 so they user can select one of them.

I kept as close to the code in the documentation as humanly possible:

```
$('#catSearchBox').select2({
    width: '500px',
    ajax: {
        url: "url/to/data",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        cache: false,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                searchKey: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            $.each(data, function(catName, catId) {
                var newOption = new Option(catId, catName, false, false);
                $('#catSearchBox').append(newOption).trigger('change');
            });
        }
    },
    placeholder: 'Suche nach Kategorie ...',
    minimumInputLength: 3
});
```

Now, everything here works up until the `append`. When I search for anything, the options are generated correctly, however, the append seems to fail as no options are displayed at all. It looks like this:

[image: select2 after search]

However, it's not because of an empty or invalid response, because the options are definitely created:

[image: option creation]

I'm kinda at a loss here, I don't see why my code is not working, especially since I kept as close as possible to the code in the documentation (https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax and https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items).

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this problem? If you need any additional information I might have missed out, please let me know.

Comment: To be sure: the API you are using to fetch the data returns the correctly formatted data?

Comment: Can you share what does `console.log(data)` returns inside `processResults` function?

Comment: @DavidGildour yes, the data is 100% correct. I've checked it many, many times.

Comment: @palaѕн The problem is solved already. As mkilmanas below pointed out, processResults has to return an object containing the results, something which I apparently missed when reading the docs.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2):

processResults Is not used to append options to the select2. It is used to transform the response from the API. It should return a valid array of objects to feed select2.

Something like:

```
var newData = [];
$.each(data, function(catName, catId) {
    newData.push({ id: catId, text: catName });
});

return { results: newData };
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main problem is in your `processResults` function and Select2's expectations of it.

From what I was able to partly read and partly deduce from the documentation at https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data is that `processResults` is supposed to **return** an object containing a key `results` and those results should be an array of objects. Further down there were some examples and [one of them](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data) shows that those objects contain 2 keys - `id` and `text`.

Moreover, the info box at [the top of the docs](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) it says that select2 will create `<option>` only for element that was chosen (it's done for performance reasons). This implies that you are not supposed to create the `<option>` elements yourself, but just return the data in the expected format and select2 will take care of the rest.

This is a fiddle based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/mkilmanas/jkx2mwv5/1/ and it doesn't work, it throws an error of trying to access `results` of undefined.

This is another fiddle with analogous behaviour but done according to those findings from the documentation: https://jsfiddle.net/mkilmanas/3s0kupaw/5/

Comment: Oh WOW, so that was the problem. I got the error message ``t is undefined``, should've suspected that was the problem. I just didn't quite understand the documentation then, alright. Thanks for the clarification and the effort you've put into the answer, I got it to work now and can remove my dirty hack! I just wish the documentation would've been a bit clearer for us people not working with JS that much.

Comment: Yeah, the docs are not superb. But I suppose it takes several years of reading docs to start noticing the small details and to look for information in unrelated sections :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is the solution but there are 2 things in your code that I don't like so much.

Try this:

```
processResults: function (data, params) {
    //  First, remove all previous elements
    $('#catSearchBox').html('');
    $.each(data, function(catName, catId) {
        var newOption = new Option(catId, catName, false, false);
        $('#catSearchBox').append(newOption);
    });
    //  Second, fire change when all elements are appended
    $('#catSearchBox').trigger('change');
}
```